# How to ping from remote server?

Tags: java, unix, ssh, ping

I have a server where I can execute ssh user@host and do ping IP next. Now I'm writing a java application that has to do same thing, first ssh and then ping. If given this

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh user@host");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping ip");
```

it doesn't work, only ssh works not ping.
Is there any way I can do both in same command or any script?
The below command executes only ping on server itself `ssh user@host ping ip`

Comment: since you are executing system calls... can you provide information about the system you are working on (is it mac? or windows? or linux?)

Comment: You may want to look into doing it through java api instead of executing shell commands:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pinging-ip-address-java/

Comment: unix @MartinFrank . Anyway why does it needed as I mentioned earlier only one command works. if uses ping it works, if uses ssh it works but using ssh with ping doesnt.

Comment: To me your question is not clear. Please [edit] it and add more details. What exactly means "*it doesn't work, only ssh works not ping*"? What happens and what do you want to happen instead? What exactly is wrong with `ssh user@host ping ip`? Can you show with shell commands what you want to achieve? What is `ip`? The IP address of `host`?  The IP address of a different system? Please don't use comments to add requested information or clarification, [edit] your question instead. Are both your local system and `host` UNIX systems?